# How can I make tcsh echo the time that a command is executed, before it is executed?

Tags: prompt, tcsh

I would like tcsh to print the time that each command is executed, preferably in the right-hand column of the screen.  This is *similar* to what `rprompt` can be used to do with the following setting,

```
set rprompt = "%P"
```

except that the above prints the time when the *prompt* was printed on the screen, *not* the time that the next *command* is executed.  I find this unhelpful; If I haven't typed a command for some time, and then execute a command, the time printed next to the command does not reflect when I executed that command.  I thought that the following would do it,

```
alias postcmd 'set rprompt="`date +%T`"'
```

by dynamically changing the value of `rprompt` before each command is executed, but this also doesn't do it; it does not update the time to the time when the command is executed.  (And actually, I don't understand why.)  Setting `precmd` doesn't do it either.

How can I accomplish this?

My question is essentially identical to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3466/how-can-i-display-the-time-when-a-command-was-executed-in-my-bash-prompt), except that I use tcsh and not bash, and the other question's accepted answer (i.e., setting `precmd`) does not appear to work for me.

Comment: I take it "history" with timestamps does not suffice for your purposes?

Comment: I do know about the history facility, but I'm hoping to find something automatic. Using the history command takes more time, disrupts your train of thought, etc.  Plus, this is one of those things that makes me think "there's just _got_ to be a way to do such a simple thing..."

Comment: The value that you want *is* shown by `rprompt`, but on the following line.  tcsh does not have a way to redraw the previously-drawn `rprompt` output.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Ah, so you mean, the `postcmd` setting is actually working, but it's just that the text is not being redrawn as expected?

Comment: yes - I didn't see any easy/portable way for you to modify this, else I would have expanded on that in an answer.